# Usage of 'almighty' in informal language

Tags: informal-language

I had always thought that *almighty* was only used in religious contexts until I came across:

> An almighty sigh of relief

which I found interesting.

I am wondering, is using *almighty* considered offensive in similar sentences (since it has a religious connotation) or is it OK to use it in a casual conversation with anyone?

Comment: @Kat Just to separate this word from the other words since, as far as I know, writing a word in bold or italics in the title is not possible. I'm not really sure if using parentheses is the best option though.

Comment: This usage is not common. I would wonder if the speaker were an unusually religious Christian.

Comment: Xerxes - the usage is _extremely_ common, among believers and non-believers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Almighty dollar" is a fairly comon idiom, usually used to criticize wealth/capitalism/greed.

"I guess people will do anything for the almighty dollar."

It is not even remotely offensive, at least in the US.